# closeOnClickOutside is not working for angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I am using 2 **angular-2-dropdown-multiselect** dropdowns in a bootstarp mega div.
when i click on the dropdown it opens. But when i click on outside the dropdwon it is not closing.[Click here to check the screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiSxf.png).
I have used "closeOnClickOutside" in the dropdown settings. But it is not working.

**app.component.ts**

```
  defaultStateSettings = {
    checkedStyle: 'fontawesome',
    enableSearch: true,
    selectionLimit: 1,
    autoUnselect: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: true,
    buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default btn-block',
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="inputStates" [(ngModel)]="offersSearchCriteriaModel.StateId" [settings]="defaultStateSettings" [texts]="defaultStateText"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

please help.

Comment: your tags are wrong, pls delete angular tag and typescript tag.

Comment: so what should be the tag ?

Comment: angularjs is correct, but angular tag is for angular 2.x >. read the tags description:

Comment: Questions about Angular (not to be confused with AngularJS), the web framework from Google. Use this tag for Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version. For the older AngularJS (1.x) web framework, use the angularjs tag.

Comment: @DanielSeguraPérez this is an Angular question, not AngularJs

Comment: yes, i was confused with another question. Sorry!

Comment: ha .. ha..  iam also confused with ur comments

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade Your angular-2-dropdown-multiselect to v1.6.3 It will work Check the

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1v7be

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done that.But Still not working

Comment: "dependencies": { "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.7.1"  }

Comment: { "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "1.6.3" } change your package like this and do npm install

Comment: may be you have some other issue. but It has some error  for v1.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177276/discussion-between-midhun-p-and-chellappan).